# TV series or Movie with tall torus-shaped spaceship?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Trying to remember a TV series or Movie that had a ship shaped like a tall torus (donut) which had windows on outside and inside that were small and think the ship was coloured red, it might be from the 1970s/1980s but can't be sure, been something I've been trying to remember for a while - hopefully someone can remember, the ship could land on a planet and wasn't too big, the hole of the torus faces up and down so the hole is tall and narrow.

Comment: Not really sure what a tall donut looks like. Do you mean a cylinder?

Comment: Yes but with rounded top and bottom, much like a donut in shape but if it were taller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember a childrens TV series that had a spacecraft that was that shape. It was a remake of Treasure Island - it was called 'Treasure Island in Outer Space'. Some episodes of this are on youtube.

- there is a shot of the spacecraft in a hangar at 1:21 on this video.

Comment: Awesome think this is exactly what I was thinking of!